# Invoking a Viewmodel Method From an Event Handler In a Resource Dictionary

Tags: wpf, events, mvvm, storyboard, resourcedictionary

What I'm trying to do is wire up the Completed event of a StoryBoard that's declared in a Resource Dictionary to invoke a method on my viewmodel.

I declared the StoryBoard in a Resource Dictionary because it's used by 5 Styles, also declared in this Resource Dictionary. My Resource Dictionary is declared as below

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Class="PrimaryAssets"
                    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:pry="clr-namespace:PowderKegSoftware.Artisan.Client.Primary"
                    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity">


    <BeginStoryboard x:Key="ShowAspect">
        <Storyboard TargetProperty="Opacity"
                    FillBehavior="HoldEnd"
                    Completed="HandleTransitionCompleted">

            <DoubleAnimation To="1"
                             Duration="0:0:0.4" />

        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard> 

.............
```

I added a method to my views code behind called `HandleTransitionCompleted` which invoked my viewmodel's method but I can't get a reference to my view from this Resource Dictionary.

I tried using a command by making `HandelTransitionCompleted` a property that holds an ICommand instance and using a command in my StoryBoard like so

```
    <BeginStoryboard x:Key="ShowAspect">
        <Storyboard TargetProperty="Opacity"
                    FillBehavior="HoldEnd">

            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Completed">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction
                        Command="{Binding Path=HandelTransitionCompleted,
                                                Mode=OneWay}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>

            <DoubleAnimation To="1"
                             Duration="0:0:0.4" />

        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>

.........
```

This throws an exception saying "Cannot freeze this Storyboard timeline ....." and after doing some reading I understand why.

Is there a way to get this event handler to invoke the method on my viewmodel.

Any help would be most welcome and thanks in advance.

Comment: You should try and add this trigger in a style that will be shared by the views. make your own view-base class, that your views could inherit. Your style will then target your new class.

Comment: @o_w  Thanks for the suggestion I will give that a try.